# Visual Studio solution explorer not showing some files that are existed in a specific folder

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

I have a big problem with git , the remote branch in github contains a commited pushed yesterday but my local branch does not contains the last changes, however , I need this commit into the local branch , I have tried many solutions but any of them works for me .

I'm trying `git pull` and `git merge` from my branch into another branches but this not worked for me .

What's wrong in this case?

**Update :** I found that the problem is coming from the VS 2019 , not the from the git tool , However, the folder contains the files but the solution explorer not showing these files.

[The commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKDa7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is coming from the VS 2019 , not the from the git tool , However, the folder contains the files but the solution explorer "not showing these files".

finally I got a simple solution :D
select "show all file" after just click right tip of the smile on the files and chose "include file"